# Gson, dynamic InstanceCreator

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

For example, there are two classes

```
class A {
    public int key;
    public B b;
}

class B {
    private final int key;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public B(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

So field **key** of inner B instance must be exactly as field **key** of outer A instance.

B's instance creator is:

```
public class B_InstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<B> {
    private final int key;

    public B_InstanceCreator(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public B createInstance(Type type) {
        return new B(key);
    }
}
```

How can I implement type adapter for A, which creates (and then uses to deserialize inner B) B_InstanceCreator just after extracting **key**?

Comment: Now I deserialize A manually (in custom type adapter) , calling `new B(key)` from the A's type adapter. It looks far from perfect solution :(

Comment: As far as I understand, you're assigning the JSON properties to the `B` instance yourself since Gson does not support objects and JSON merge?

Comment: That's right. I had a hope that Gson can extract A and B automatically, with passing `key` to B. But, you right, seems now it's not possible.

Comment: But you can avoid manual properties-to-fields assignment and still use a context-aware `InstanceCreator` in order to deserialize `B` instances as I described in my answer. Note that you don't have to make assignment yourself then delegating this job to Gson via the instance creator (thus your `B` can contain `@SerializedName`, `@Expose`, etc).

Comment: Yes, that's thing I got from you answer! Unfortunately the most pain for me is A, cause it has a lot of fields, I need to extract each of them manually.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm fully with you on that: I hate to use `JsonDeserializer`s because they require a lot of job to be done manually. Just a question: is `A` supposed to be the root of the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: Yes, A is the root.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. It's a bit complicated, but is able to map all the fields for you.

Answer (score 3):

Gson seems to be extremely stateless, and it hurts sometimes. The same story is relevant to `InstanceCreator` where the context is passed via a constructor or setters of an object implementing this interface like you menitoned above. Obtaining the `key` is only possible when deserializing the `A` class since the classes of the child nodes are not aware of its parent object context. So you have to implement a deserializer for the `A` class first (unfortunately losing annotations like `@SerializedName`, `@Expose`, `@JsonAdapter`...):

```
final class AJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<A> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<A> aJsonDeserializer = new AJsonDeserializer();

    private AJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<A> getAJsonDeserializer() {
        return aJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public A deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject root = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        final A a = new A();
        a.key = root.get("key").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt();
        a.b = createInnerGson(a.key).fromJson(root.get("b"), B.class);
        return a;
    }

    private static Gson createInnerGson(final int key) {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(B.class, (InstanceCreator<B>) type -> new B(key))
                .create();
    }

}
```

As you can see above, its another performance-weak place is `createInnerGson` that instantiates a Gson builder, an instance creator, and finally the inner Gson instance behind the scenes (don't know how much it costs). But it seems to be the only way to pass the `key` context to the instance creator. (It would be nice if Gson could implement a `fromJson` method to *overwrite* the state of a `B` instance (say, something like `gson.merge(someJson, someBInstance)`) -- but Gson can only produce *new* deserialized values.)

The JSON deserializer can be used as follows (assuming `A` and `B` have pretty-print implemented in their respective `toString` methods):

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(A.class, getAJsonDeserializer())
        .create();
final A a = gson.fromJson("{\"key\":2048,\"b\":{\"x\":20,\"y\":30}}", A.class);
out.printf("%d, %d\n", a.key, a.b.key);
out.println(a);
```

Output:

```
2048, 2048
A{key=2048, b=B{key=2048, x=20, y=30}}
```

---

### V2

You know, I have an idea... `JsonDeserializer<A>` probably was not that a good idea requiring semi-manual `A` deserializing. However, an alternatve solution is nesting a real deserializer into a sort of a "shadow" generic deserializer, thus delegating the whole deserialiation job to Gson. The only thing here is that you have to remember that "shadow root" Gson instances should be used for the objects you mentioned as top-most (the root), otherwise it won't work as you might expect or might affect performance (see how nested Gson instances are obtained below).

#### GsonFactoryJsonDeserializer.java

Let's first take a quick look on this class. It does not make deserialization itself and just asks for another Gson instance to perform deserialization. It has two factory methods: one for direct mapping between `JsonElement` to `Gson`, and one for having two operations like extracting a key from `JsonElement` and delegating the key to the `Gson` factory (remember the specifics of `InstanceCreator` discussed above?). This deserializer actually does nothing more than just obtaining the root JSON element.

```java
final class GsonFactoryJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    private final Function<? super JsonElement, Gson> gsonFactory;

    private GsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(final Function<? super JsonElement, Gson> gsonFactory) {
        this.gsonFactory = gsonFactory;
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Object> gsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(final Function<? super JsonElement, Gson> gsonFactory) {
        return new GsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(gsonFactory);
    }

    static <K> JsonDeserializer<Object> gsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(final Function<? super JsonElement, ? extends K> jsonElementToKey,
            final Function<? super K, Gson> keyToGson) {
        return new GsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(jsonElementToKey.andThen(keyToGson));
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final Gson gson = gsonFactory.apply(jsonElement);
        return gson.fromJson(jsonElement, type);
    }

}
```

#### Demo

The demo below encapsulates a `GsonBuilder` factory method in order to create a new `GsonBuilder` instance on demand because Gson builders are stateful and using the same instance may leed to pretty unexpected behavior. `gsonFactoryJsonDeserializer` is using the second overload: to separate key extraction and registering the `B` class instantiator. If the keys in outer and inner objects does not match (`a.key` must equal `a.b.key`), the application should throw an assertion error that should never happen in production.

```java
private static GsonBuilder createDefaultRealGsonBuilder() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            // build your "real" Gson builder here by registering necessary type adapters, etc...
            ;
}

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson rootGson = createDefaultRealGsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(
                    A.class,
                    gsonFactoryJsonDeserializer(
                            jsonElement -> jsonElement.getAsJsonObject()
                                    .get("key")
                                    .getAsJsonPrimitive()
                                    .getAsInt()
                            ,
                            key -> createDefaultRealGsonBuilder()
                                    .registerTypeAdapter(B.class, (InstanceCreator<B>) type -> new B(key))
                                    .create()
                    )
            )
            .create();
    final A a = rootGson.fromJson("{\"key\":2048,\"b\":{\"x\":20,\"y\":30}}", A.class);
    if ( a.key != a.b.key ) {
        throw new AssertionError("NOT working!");
    }
    out.println("Working.");
}
```

Output:

> Working.

Note that I didn't make any performance testing, and unfortunately creating new Gson instances seems to be the only way of doing what you were asking for.